# How to automate find/replace code in VBA modules in MS Office 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, vbe

I have a large number of Excel Templates that contain VBA code that need to be updated. The Find method of the code-module object only returns true/false, not the location of the found string.

Is there any way to automate the find-and-replace procedure?

Comment: Post the code of the codemodule.  .Find itself returns a Range object which should yield location.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to a new macro-enabled workbook. Set the `FIND_WHAT` and `REPLACE_WITH` constants, open the other workbooks and run the code.

The original code comes from [Charles Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

WARNING: Only basic testing has been done!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceTextInCodeModules()

' Must add a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"
' Also must set "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
' See the url below for more info on these.
' Based on code found at:
' Source: www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx Copyright 2013, Charles H. Pearson

Dim theWorkbook As Workbook
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Long ' end line
Dim lineNum As Long
Dim thisLine As String
Dim message As String
Dim numFound As Long

Const FIND_WHAT As String = "findthis"
Const REPLACE_WITH As String = "replaced"

    numFound = 0

    For Each theWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
        If theWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            If theWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                Set VBProj = theWorkbook.VBProject
                For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
                    'Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
                    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

                    With CodeMod
                        numLines = .CountOfLines
                        For lineNum = 1 To numLines
                            thisLine = .Lines(lineNum, 1)
                            If InStr(1, thisLine, FIND_WHAT, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                message = message & theWorkbook.Name & " | " & VBComp.Name & " | Line #" & lineNum & vbNewLine
                                .ReplaceLine lineNum, Replace(thisLine, FIND_WHAT, REPLACE_WITH, , , vbTextCompare)
                                numFound = numFound + 1
                            End If
                        Next lineNum
                    End With
                Next VBComp
            End If
        End If
    Next theWorkbook

    Debug.Print "Found: " & numFound
    If message <> "" Then
        Debug.Print message
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "Must add a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"" - this can be avoided if VBIDE definitions are not declared and Option Explicit removed

Comment: To set "Trust access to the VBA project object model", then from VBA you can do `Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Id:=3627).Execute`